# Key:Value Pairs from txt file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a txt file with key value pairs. It can format (get, retrieve) the pairs from the file in multiple ways, for example:

as line separated strings with colons:

```
stringa1:stringa2
stringb1:stringb2
```

or as line separated strings with commas:

```
stringa1,stringa2
stringb1,stringb2
```

or as individuals lists of strings:

```
[stringa1,stringa2]
['stringa1','stringa2']
```

AND, I can assign each string to a variable with:

```
    for string in list
        splitstring=list.split(',')    
        for item in splitstring:
            print (item)
    >>>stringa1
    >>>stringa2
```

But I can't figure out how to add those key:value pairs to a dictionary

Comment: Parsing list of 3 pattern is already solved? Your code seems to only parse pattern of "stringa1,stringa2\nstringb1,stringb2".

Comment: Yea, well..I gotta crawl before I can run. Only my 3rd week of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d[splitstring[0]] = splitstring[1]
```

should work, where d is a dict. That's the easiest way of adding a key, value pair to a dictionary.

Another way is:

```
d.update({splitstring[0]: splitstring[1]})
```

Comment: Of Course!!! Reference the items in the list from their Index. Thanks, it works. Now I have to deal with my 'IndexError: list index out of range' exception. But I'll get it.  ---GOT IT.

Answer (score 1):

Taking in mind that we are talking about pairs, then
this should work:

```
mydict = {}
for i in range(0,len(splitstring),2):
    mydict[splitstring[i]] = splitstring[i+1]
```